# Getting post author and date in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, author

I am using the below code to obtain post information in Wordpress. I have found this code online and have added the two variables "date" and "author". However, these are not currently working as required/expected.

For "date" it is returning the full date/time stamp (i.e 2017-03-08 15:12:39) rather than the nicely formatted date retrieved when using get_the_date(); (i.e 8th March 2017). Can I adjust my markup to format the date?

For "author", nothing at all is being returned?

Thanks in advance.

```
$postData = get_posts($postParameters);
$posts = array();

foreach($postData as $post) {
    $post = array(
        "id"       => $post->ID,
        "title"    => $post->post_title,
        "excerpt"  => $post->post_excerpt,
        "date"     => $post->post_date,
        "author"   => $post->post_author,
        "slug"     => $post->slug,
        "image"    => array("url" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID)),
        "link"     => get_permalink($post->ID),
        "category" => get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->name
    );

    array_push($posts, $post);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are retrieving an object, after you receive the data you need to format it the way you need it. For example:

This will retrieve the Object with the post information:

```
<?php $postData = get_posts($postParameters);?>
```

Now from the object, you received the date as:

```
[post_date] => 2016-09-20 15:42:55
```

So to show it as a nice date you need to format it like this:

```
<?php echo '<p>'.get_the_date( 'F, j Y', $postData[0]->ID ).'</p>'; ?>
```

And with the Author, the object return the author ID which is a number:

```
[post_author] => 1
```

Now with the following code you can show the Author display name:

```
<?php echo '<p>'.the_author_meta( 'display_name', $postData[0]->post_author ).'</p>'; ?>
```

I hope it can help you!
Enjoy!